# Javascript Calculator does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I have this calculator
http://jsfiddle.net/DPqXE/

HTML

```
<p>With numbers &rarr; 
<input id="mli" name="mli" style="width:50px;" type="text" />&nbsp;ml.</p>
<p>
With numbers &rarr; <input id="sprying" name="sprying" style="width:50px;" type="text" />&nbsp;time/s</p>
<p>
How often&rarr; <select id="week" name="week"><option value="4.3">1</option><option value="8.6">2</option><option value="12.9">3</option><option value="17.2">4</option><option value="21.5">5</option><option value="24.8">6</option><option value="30.1">7</option></select>
<p>
Total: <span id="total">&bull;&bull;</span> months</p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sprying').keyup(function(ev){
    var total = Math.round((
    ($('#mli').val() * 14.7) / ($('#sprying').val() * $( "#week option:selected" ).val() )));
    $('#total').html(total);
});
});
```

But I have an issue:
When I type some numbers in to the input fields 
total is calculated, but when I chose from the select fields nothing hapens.

And after that if i edit the first two fields the result is calculated properly.

Many thanks

Comment: You have only one text box that is bound to an event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would it, you only listen to keyup.

`bind` both `keyup` and `change`, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sprying').keyup(updateTotals);
    $('#week').change(updateTotals);
    function updateTotals(){
        var total = Math.round((
        ($('#mli').val() * 14.7) / ($('#sprying').val() * $( "#week option:selected" ).val() )));
        $('#total').html(total);
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DPqXE/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are assigned `.keyup()` only, also asign to `.change()`

Add it in your `$(document).ready(function() {..}`

```
$('#week').change(function(ev){
    //....
});
```

Comment: I didn't -1 you, but possibly due to duplicating the code which is a code smell (DRY).